# How to detect Microsoft Chromium Edge (chredge , edgium) in Javascript

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium, browser-detection, data-uri

'Edge 75' will be (is?) the first Chromium Based Edge browser. How can I check if this browser is Edge on Chrome ?

(What I really want to know is if the browser fully supports data-uri's - https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri - so feature detection would even be better. If you know a way to do that, I can change the question)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use the window.navigator userAgent to check whether the browser is Microsoft Chromium Edge or Chrome.

Code as below:

```js
<script>
    var browser = (function (agent) {
        switch (true) {
            case agent.indexOf("edge") > -1: return "edge";
            case agent.indexOf("edg/") > -1: return "chromium based edge (dev or canary)"; // Match also / to avoid matching for the older Edge
            case agent.indexOf("opr") > -1 && !!window.opr: return "opera";
            case agent.indexOf("chrome") > -1 && !!window.chrome: return "chrome";
            case agent.indexOf("trident") > -1: return "ie";
            case agent.indexOf("firefox") > -1: return "firefox";
            case agent.indexOf("safari") > -1: return "safari";
            default: return "other";
        }
    })(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
    document.body.innerHTML = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() + "<br>" + browser;
</script>
```

The Chrome browser userAgent:

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
> like gecko) chrome/74.0.3729.169 safari/537.36

The Edge browser userAgent:

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
> like gecko) chrome/64.0.3282.140 safari/537.36 edge/18.17763

The Microsoft Chromium Edge Dev userAgent:

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
> like gecko) chrome/76.0.3800.0 safari/537.36 edg/76.0.167.1

The Microsoft Chromium Edge Canary userAgent:

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
> like gecko) chrome/76.0.3800.0 safari/537.36 edg/76.0.167.1

As we can see that Microsoft Chromium Edge userAgent contains the "**edg**" keyword, we could use it to detect whether the browser is Chromium Edge browser or Chrome browser.

Comment: Except edge contains edg so saying _contains the "edg" keyword_ is misleading. Also, I think that the word _keyword_ is overused. Would it work to test for the text "edg/"?

Comment: It works, but code is weird... Plus that last line ...

Answer (score 8):

Using CanIUse, the most universal feature which is **unsupported** on old Edge (which used the EdgeHtml engine) but **supported** in Edge Chromium and everywhere else (except IE), is the **[reversed attribute on an OL list](https://caniuse.com/#search=reversed)**. This attribute has the advantage of having been supported for ages in everything else.

(This is the only one I can find which covers all other browsers including Opera Mini; if that's not a worry for you there are [plenty of others](https://caniuse.com/#compare=edge+18,edge+79).)

So, you can use simple feature detection to see if you're on Old Edge (or IE) -

```
var isOldEdgeOrIE = !('reversed' in document.createElement('ol'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I found this question from the other side, how to actually check if a pre-chromium-edge is being used, I found the following solution (IE checks included):

```
  // Edge < 18
  if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge') !== -1) {
    return true;
  }
  // IE 11
  if (window.document.documentMode) {
    return true;
  }
  // IE 10
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE 10') !== -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
```