# What is the correct way to detect new Microsoft Edge v80 (Blink) via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

As latest version of Microsoft Edge is [out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge#Release_history) and uses Blink - what is the correct way to differentiate Old Edge from New Edge one with javascript?

[image]

Currently I plan to look into `navigator.userAgent` to check for older versions of Edge (up to 18)

```
const isOldEdge = /edge\/([0-1][0-8]|[0-9]\D)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
```

Is this correct way to detect it?

Comment: It is usually better to detect features instead of versions. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: currently I'm styling html5 range input that has gradient track and `Old Edge` requires another approach as it doesn't allow to style the full track (only separate parts before  and after thumb). not sure how to test this feature

Comment: You can probably test that with [CSS feature queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Conditional_Rules/Using_Feature_Queries).

Comment: @str  I need to test for selectors `::-ms-fill-lower {...}` & `::-ms-fill-upper`, not features - I dont think this will help here. I can test for specific features support to determine I'm in Old Edge but that seems to be less obvious and more fragile

Comment: For that you could use a linear gradient that "moves" based on the current range input value. That would work cross-browser, including old versions of Edge.

Comment: @str thats what I'm doing - I want to draw absolute `<div>` with `linear-gradient` only for old edge - for new browsers I paint the `track` itself

Comment: I've suggested a feature-detection method here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61822728/548664

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you use **window.navigator** userAgent to check whether the browser is Microsoft Chromium Edge or MS edge (EdgeHtml).

The Edge (EdgeHtml) browser userAgent:

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
>   like gecko) chrome/70.0.3538.102 safari/537.36 edge/18.18362

The Microsoft Chromium Edge userAgent:

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
>   like gecko) chrome/80.0.3987.87 safari/537.36 edg/80.0.361.50

Sample code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var browser = (function (agent) {
        switch (true) {
            case agent.indexOf("edge") > -1: return "MS Edge (EdgeHtml)";
            case agent.indexOf("edg") > -1: return "MS Edge Chromium";
            case agent.indexOf("opr") > -1 && !!window.opr: return "opera";
            case agent.indexOf("chrome") > -1 && !!window.chrome: return "chrome";
            case agent.indexOf("trident") > -1: return "Internet Explorer";
            case agent.indexOf("firefox") > -1: return "firefox";
            case agent.indexOf("safari") > -1: return "safari";
            default: return "other";
        }
    })(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
    document.body.innerHTML =  "This is " + browser + " browser." + "<br><br>" + window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS edge (EdgeHtml) browser:

[image]

Output in MS edge Chromium browser:

[image]

Reference:

[How to detect Microsoft Chromium Edge (chredge , edgium) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360225/how-to-detect-microsoft-chromium-edge-chredge-edgium-in-javascript)

Comment: yeah I noticed that `edge/edg` difference but I want to be more specific thats why I use versions in regexp - do you think its safe to rely on `edge/edg`? tomorrow it might be changed back to `edge` I guess

Comment: at present, there is no news that edg will get replaced with edge in user agent string. So you can use it to identify the chromium Edge browser.