# How to detect browser for chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I want to detect if the browser is chrome. I came across a lot of answers but all of them return true also for opera and the new version of edge. 
I was wondering if you have the best way to detect if the browser is chrome

[edit] Code i've tested so far that return true :

```js
//Test 1 => Opera and edge returns true
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
// Test 2 => return false for chrome latest version
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
//Test 3 => same as test 1
var is_chrome = /chrome/i.test( navigator.userAgent );
```

Comment: Why would the browser matter?

Comment: The best way is to not do it in the first place. Check for features and not for browsers.

Comment: I have a bug fix but it's only relevent to include it for chrome as my bug exist only in chrome

Comment: _"...also for opera and the new version of edge"_ - Because both use Chromium

Comment: If you need to "fix" something for Chrome/Chromium only you're doing something wrong - imho.

Comment: @Andreas so no way to do it in your opinion ? :/

Comment: "_I came across a lot of answers but all of them return true_" what answers? Update your post with all the code that you have tried so that others don't post the same answer again here.

Comment: If the bug is coming from not supported browser API or similar, you can try https://modernizr.com/

Comment: This is an XY Problem - you should be asking how to fix your bug in a cross-browser manner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you can refer to this code example that may help you to identify the MS Edge legacy, Ms. Edge Chromium, Opera, Google Chrome, IE, Firefox, and Safari browser.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var browser = (function (agent) {
        switch (true) {
            case agent.indexOf("edge") > -1: return "MS Edge (EdgeHtml)";
            case agent.indexOf("edg") > -1: return "MS Edge Chromium";
            case agent.indexOf("opr") > -1 && !!window.opr: return "opera";
            case agent.indexOf("chrome") > -1 && !!window.chrome: return "chrome";
            case agent.indexOf("trident") > -1: return "Internet Explorer";
            case agent.indexOf("firefox") > -1: return "firefox";
            case agent.indexOf("safari") > -1: return "safari";
            default: return "other";
        }
    })(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
    document.body.innerHTML =  "This is " + browser + " browser." + "<br><br>" + window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge (Chromium) browser:

[image]

Output in Google Chrome browser:

[image]

Output in Opera browser:

[image]

Reference:

[What is the correct way to detect new Microsoft Edge v80 (Blink) via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185295/what-is-the-correct-way-to-detect-new-microsoft-edge-v80-blink-via-javascript/60199162#60199162)