# Detect edge (chromium) browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, browser-detection

On a specific website I am unable to detect if the browser is edge (chromium) because on that website I am getting following user agent on edge browser

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"
```

There is no "edge" or "edg" keyword to detect if it's edge is there any work around for this issue.

I need to just differentiate between these two browsers only, here is my code for detection.

```
public isChrome(): boolean {
    return /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
}

public isEdge(): boolean {
    return /edg|edge/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure that useragent is from Edge? Never seen an Useragent from Edge without "EDG"

Answer (score 0):

I think the userAgent you provided is from Chrome instead of MS Edge. The userAgent of MS Edge should have **edg/version** at the end. For example:

```
mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/91.0.4472.101 safari/537.36 edg/91.0.864.48
```

For details, you could also refer to this document:[How to detect Microsoft Edge in your website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/user-agent-guidance).
If you want to determine the browser used by the user, you can refer to this case:[How to detect Microsoft Chromium Edge (chredge , edgium) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360225/how-to-detect-microsoft-chromium-edge-chredge-edgium-in-javascript)